# How to fix 'failed: Permission denied (13)'

Tags: php, mysql

Yesterday I was trying to install a panel on my VPS, Pterodactyl. But it ended up giving problems and I gave up. But, I got this error

**PHP 7.3, Apache 2.0 and MySQL 5**

```py
Warning in ./libraries/session.inc.php#105
session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_eok8aia21ebtl8i59i6p4u6sa5, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

Backtrace

./libraries/session.inc.php#105: session_start()
./libraries/common.inc.php#350: require(./libraries/session.inc.php)
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
Warning in ./libraries/session.inc.php#105
session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /var/lib/php/session)

Backtrace

./libraries/session.inc.php#105: session_start()
./libraries/common.inc.php#350: require(./libraries/session.inc.php)
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

Comment: Does the user you're running php-cli or apache have write permission in /var/lib/php/session/ folder?

Comment: I can not say. Can you help me? I'm new with Linux/CentOS 7 system. I'm logged in with root (Se você for brasileiro, me fala)

Comment: Run htop, press f4 to filter processes, than type apache2 or php, check which user owns the process, than use "ls -lah /var/lib/php/session", and check if the owner matches the user you found.

Comment: Btw, if you don't have htop, install with "sudo apt install htop" or "sudo yum install htop", i don't know which of these CentOS uses.

Comment: I made. But there were no such processes. I use CentOS 7.

Only when I gave the command "ls -lah /var/ ib/php/session"

Comment: If you're on CentOS 7 the httpd user will be 'apache'. The results of `ls -l /var/lib/php/` should show you a `session` directory with an owner:group of root:apache and a file mask of  770 (rwxrwx---). Otherwise, the web server will not be able to write inside this directory.